# Is there any way to run the code of Cloud Firestore before the addOnCompleteListener´s code?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to run the code in addOnSuccessListener after the one before, but the code related to the Cloud Firestore is ran after the code in the addOnSuccessListener

```
db.collection("users").get().addOnSuccessListener { users ->
  for(documento in users){
    documento.reference.collection("puntuaciones").       
     document("puntuaciones").get().addOnSuccessListener {
      var partidas = it.get("numPartidas") as Long? ?: 0
      println("EMAIL: ${documento}, PARTIDAS: $partidas")
      while (partidas > 0) {
        entrada = Array<String>(2) { _ -> ""}
        entrada[0]=email ?:"Sin registrar"
        entrada[1] = java.lang.String.valueOf(it.get(partidas.toString())) as String
        puntuaciones.add(entrada)
        partidas--
      }
  }
  rankingRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(
    this,
    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
    false
  )
  println("PUNTUACIONES $puntuaciones")
  var adaptador = AdapterRanking(puntuaciones)
  rankingRecycler.adapter = adaptador
}
```

It prints "PUNTUACIONES []" because it runs before the last part of the code and I don´t know why
The output is:

```
PUNTUACIONES []
EMAIL: ..., PARTIDAS: 4
EMAIL: ..., PARTIDAS: 1
EMAIL: ..., PARTIDAS: 0
EMAIL: ..., PARTIDAS: 5
```

and it should be:

```
EMAIL: ..., PARTIDAS: 4
EMAIL: ..., PARTIDAS: 1
EMAIL: ..., PARTIDAS: 0
EMAIL: ..., PARTIDAS: 5
PUNTUACIONES [.........] //(one per each "partida")
```

Comment: Why are you using addOnSuccessListener twice?  Can't you just use it once and determine the order of execution within the single callback?

Comment: If I remove the second one, the result is the same, i will upload the question without the second addOnSuccessListener

Comment: Why would you do something like that? In the second loop, you aren't using something from the first one. As Doug Stevenson mentioned in his comment, when not to use a single one?

Comment: I need from the first loop the ArrayList "puntuaciones"

Comment: If you mean the first and second addOnSuccessListener (lines 1 and 3) I need go through all documents. Thats why I need separate them with a for between them